# GetElementById, am I pulling using the correct properties?

Tags: javascript

I don't think it's an onload issue anymore since I used the window.onload function. Here is the relevant pieces of the code. The console is saying the capitals is undefined. I thought I was defining it when I declared the value.

Thanks in advance!

```
<form name="shares">
  <table>
    <tr><td>Enter information here:</td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Capital to Invest</td>
      <td id="capitalr"><input type="text" name="capital" onchange="calculate();">  </td> 
    </tr>
</form>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML="Hello";   
  var capitals = document.getElementById("capitalr");
  var x = capitals.id;
  var pps = document.shares.price.value;
};

function calculate () {
  console.log("Hey");
  console.log(capitals);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the variable within a function scope, which makes it inaccessible from outside that function scope. Define it outside and it will work:

```
var capitals;
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML="Hello";   
  capitals = document.getElementById("capitalr");
  var x = capitals.id;
  var pps = document.shares.price.value;
};

function calculate () {
  console.log("Hey");
  console.log(capitals);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Rob! It's still not working.  Now, the error message has changed from "Uncaught ReferenceError: capitals is not defined" to simply just "undefined"

Comment: I just noticed that capitalr is the name of the `td` and not the `input`, therein lies the problem, you are targeting the wrong element (`td`s don't have an `onchange` event)